# Web.Debug.Config with different connection strrings

Tags: web-config, web-config-transform

I have a Web.config file and a Web.Debug.Config file.  My Web.Debug.Config file is practically empty and I would like to add to it a connectionstrings section to override the one in the Web.Config file.  I tried just adding the connectionstrings section in the config file but it didn't pick it up.  I know there are some commands I need to use in one or both config files but am not sure what they are.  Can someone help me out please?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: What sort of project is it? Console applications (e.g.) don't perform transformations as standard - you'd need something like [Slow Cheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) for them...

Comment: @SteveWilkes I assumed the **Web**.Config gave it away? :)

Comment: @Wayne Cornish, stranger things have happened, didn't hurt to ask :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do the following (not tested, but should work) to replace the Web.Config file's connectionStrings section:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <add name="AuthenticationDatabase" connectionString="connection-string-here" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="OtherDatabase" connectionString="connection-string-here" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

If you're just looking to update an existing connectionString:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="AuthenticationDatabase" connectionString="new-string-here" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```